# SUM and GROUP results from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - one for the daily revenue, one for daily costs.

There's one revenue for each date

```
+------------+---------+
| date       | revenue |
+------------+---------+
| 2017-01-04 | 100     |
| 2017-01-05 | 150     |
| 2017-01-06 | 200     |
...
```

There's none, one or more costs for each date.

```
+------------+---------+
| date       | cost    |
+------------+---------+
| 2017-01-04 | 17      |
| 2017-01-04 | 32      |
| 2017-01-06 | 55      |
| 2017-01-07 | 10      |
...
```

I now want to group the data by month... the result should be a table listing the summed revenue as well as the summed costs for each month:

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| month   | revenue  | costs |
+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017-01 | 4400,00  | 80,00 |
| 2017-02 | 2100,00  | 70,00 |
| 2017-03 | 5500,00  | 90,00 |
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what's your data and table schema?

Comment: where is your sql query ?

Comment: i don't have a sql query because i just don't know how to approach this... summing by date would be no problem, but by month? no idea..

Comment: there is a month function

Comment: I know the month function.. the problem is summing x items per month from one table and y items per month from another table and joining the results..

how does the month function solve that?

i know how to get the summed revenue per month using the month function - the same works for the costs ... but how can i do one query to get both?

Comment: Search for mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation.

Comment: Please show us your reflexion or at least a fiddle.

Comment: I will try to formulate the question better the next time.... thanks anyways for the quick help, problem solved!

Comment: Beware of assumptions that there will always be a revenue for each month and that there are never costs for which there is no revenue.

Comment: the selected solution seems to work even for those cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your expectation.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
   date datetime,
   revenue int
);

CREATE TABLE T2
(
   date datetime,
   cost int
);


INSERT INTO T1 (date,revenue)
VALUES 
('2017-01-04',100),
('2017-01-05',150),
('2017-01-06',200),
('2017-02-06',200);



INSERT INTO T2 (date,cost)
VALUES 
('2017-01-04',17),
('2017-01-04',32),
('2017-01-06',55),
('2017-01-07',10),
('2017-02-07',10);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T1.MONTH,revenue,costs FROM
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS 'month'
         ,SUM(revenue) AS 'revenue'
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
) AS T1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS 'month'
         ,SUM(cost)  AS 'costs'
  FROM T2
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
) AS T2
ON T1.month = T2.month
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c7e9c/2)

Comment: if you have a answer, please post it. Thanks.

Comment: for some odd reason, I cannot access the link.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'revenue' THEN amount END),0) revenue
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'cost' THEN amount END),0) cost
  FROM 
     ( SELECT date, 'revenue' type, revenue amount FROM revenue
       UNION ALL
       SELECT date, 'cost', cost FROM costs
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY yearmonth;
```